# Turning a DLL (and associated VBA) into an XLL

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

As a summer project, I got handed a large C++ file with numerous (over 50) functions and was asked to make it interface with Excel.  I created a DLL from the C++ file and wrote some VBA procedures to create function wrappers, function wizards, and populate cell ranges with the correct data.

As I have to hand this off to someone else, I would like to turn this into an XLL add-in so the pathway to the DLL in the VBA "Declare Function" doesn't get broken, as well as having a cleaner setup.

My question is, what becomes of the VBA code in the process of turning this into an XLL add-in?  Do those functions have to be re-written into the C++ file?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The XLL interface does not cover as much of the Excel object model as VBA, and is less productive for user interface tasks. But it has many advantages over VBA for building UDFs (performance, UDF registration, multithreading etc).

So my recommendation would be to convert all the UDFs to XLL but keep the function wizards and any other user interface stuff in a VBA XLAM.

Comment: Thanks Charles, that sounds like the way to go.  -Chris